# Wordpress site doesn't stop loading

Tags: wordpress

I have a big problem. My Wordpress site doesn't stop loading. The blue circle in Firefox always shows loading and I don't know why. Could it be a loop? Do you now a way to track whats loading there?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to your browser dev tools and the console, network tab.

The page is maybe trying to get some external (or internal) assets that doesn't exists anymore or unavailable.

You can, also install a plugin like Query Monitor to see different details about the page loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the http daemon error log? the php error logs? these should show give you an indication of what if anything is going wrong.